# On the Schur's Theorem

Tags: group-theory

One of the famous theorems of Schur is that "if $[G\colon Z(G)]<\infty$ then $|G'|<\infty$. There are at least two proofs: (1) by transfer homomorphism (Robinson, Ch.10) (2) by a commutator identity:

> (*) for $r\geq 1$, 
>   $[a,b]^r=(ba)^{-r}(ab)^rc_{r-1}c_{r-2}\cdots c_1$  ($c_i$'s are commutators and  $[a,b]\colon=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$)

(Rotman, Chapter on Central Series/Nilpotent Groups).

The proof given in Rotman is not clear to me. The proof is as follows: we use (*).

Let $[G\colon Z(G)]=n$. Then $G'$ is generated by at most $n^2$ commutators, which can be formed by elements of $G$ modulo $Z(G)$. Also, $g^n\in Z(G)$ for every $g\in G$. As $(ab)^n$ and $(ba)^n$ are conjugate as well as central, they are equal. Hence by (*), with $r=n$, $[a,b]^n$ is a product of $n-1$ commutators.

(Here is a difficulty) Consider a particular element of $G'$ of the following type: $c_1c_2c_1\cdots c_k$. The trick used is to collect $c_1$'s to the left in this element. To do this, we note that

> (**) $c_2c_1=c_1c_2[c_2,c_1]$.

So the given element of $G'$ is $c_1c_1c_2[c_2,c_1]\cdots c_k=c_1^2c_2[c_2,c_1]\cdots c_k$.

My question is *can the commutator $c_1$ appear in reduced form of $[c_2,c_1]$.*

I mean, although we are first collecting the terms $c_1$'s to the left by using (**), how do we ensure that the term $c_1$ will not appear in the new commutators as in RHS of $(**)$?

(If the question is not clear, please suggest to modify.)

Comment: I just looked at the proof in Rotman, and he is not replacing $c_1c_2c_1$ by $c_1^2c_2[c_2,c_1]$ (which would be replacing a product of 3 commutators by a product of 4 commutators), but by $c_1^2(c_1^{-1}c_2c_1)$. So he is replacing a product of 3 commutators by another product of 3 commutators, but with the two instances of $c_1$ brought together. So if he can collect $n$ $c_1$s together to get $c_1^n$, then he can reduce the total length of the product.

Comment: @Derek Holt: I will look at it again. Thank you very much for noticing a mistake in my reading/understanding.